# `ibuffer-switch-to-saved-filter-groups' is not known to be defined

Tags: flycheck, functions

I have this line in my `.emacs` file.

```
(add-hook 'ibuffer-mode-hook
          #'(lambda ()
              (ibuffer-switch-to-saved-filter-groups "default")))
```

*The settings work fine for me.* But **flycheck** says:

```
the function `ibuffer-switch-to-saved-filter-groups' is not known to be defined.
```

I think if I declare the function ahead, the warning would go away. But `ibuffer` is a build-in package, and I cannot find a way to declare this function.

How to declare a built-in function?

## Update

I found the `ibuffer-switch-to-saved-filter-groups` is not a built-in function, but is defined in a file called `ibuf-ext.el`, and `locate-library` can find this file from my environment path. But even after I defined `declare-function` like below:

```
(declare-function ibuffer-switch-to-saved-filters "ibuf-ext.el" nil)
```

I still get this warning from *flycheck*.

Comment: My question was not about the ibuffer settings, it was about the flycheck warning...

Comment: That is for authors of elisp packages to check if there're errors in their package file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `declare-function` doesn't silence the warning because it doesn't declare the same function (there a "-group" missing before the final "s").

The warning basically tells you that the byte-compiler can't find anything in your code which guarantees that `ibuffer-switch-to-saved-filter-groups` will exist when that call is reached.

The problem is fundamentally due to the byte-compiler's much too limited understanding of things like hooks: it is not able to understand that this `ibuffer-mode-hook` will only be run from code inside ibuffer.el (where `ibuffer-loaddefs` is loaded), so the functions placed on this hook will normally only be run in a context where `ibuffer-switch-to-saved-filter-groups` is autoloaded ondemand).

Patches welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `(require 'ibuf-ext)` will probably pacify flycheck...